# ANTLR 2 Token Stream Multiplexing: why are my tokens out of order?

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, lexical-analysis, antlr2

I am writing grammar for multi line strings (Text Block) in java. The delimiter for the start and end of a text block is triple quotes.  I can successfully parse and build the AST for the text blocks and its content, except for one issue: the `TEXT_BLOCK_START` token is being returned after the tokens from the second lexer.  I am using [this](https://www.antlr2.org/doc/streams.html) as a guide: [flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rAFs.gif). According to the ANTLR2 documentation, the way that I have implemented this should produce the desired token stream:

`TEXT_BLOCK_START` -> `content from second lexer, etc...` -> `TEXT_BLOCK_END`

I have tried changing the order of the action and the delimiter, the order of the rules, and using `select()` instead of `selector.push()`.

Here are the important parts of the main class:

```
final Lexer lexer = new Lexer(reader);
lexer.setCommentListener(contents);

final Lexer secondLexer =
                new Lexer(lexer.getInputState());

lexer.setTokenObjectClass("antlr.CommonHiddenStreamToken");
secondLexer.setTokenObjectClass("antlr.CommonHiddenStreamToken");

final TokenStreamHiddenTokenFilter filter = new 
    TokenStreamHiddenTokenFilter(lexer);

final TokenStreamSelector selector = new TokenStreamSelector();
lexer.selector = selector;
secondLexer.selector = selector;
selector.addInputStream(filter, "filter");
selector.addInputStream(secondLexer, "secondLexer");
selector.select(filter);
```

The lexer (main lexer) rule:

```
TEXT_BLOCK_START
    :   "\"\"\"" {selector.push("secondLexer");}
    ;
```

The secondary lexer rule:

```
TEXT_BLOCK_END
   : "\"\"\"" {selector.pop();}
   ;
```

As stated above, everything parses as expected, except that the token stream looks like this:

`content from second lexer, etc...` -> `TEXT_BLOCK_END` -> `TEXT_BLOCK_START`

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don’t think there are many people here able to help you with such an old version. If possible, use ANTLR 4 instead.

Comment: @BartKiers thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, at this time, ANTLR2 is a requirement. Is there a better place to ask for help?  I've also posted this question to the ANTLR mailing list.

Comment: I've not been a frequent visitor on the mailinglist, but I think you can expect an answer there sooner than here. Many of the (little bit) more complicated ANTLR 2 questions here go unanswered, is my experience. Anyway, best of luck!